# How do I write a Rails 3.1 engine controller test in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I have written a Rails 3.1 engine with the namespace Posts. Hence, my controllers are found in app/controllers/posts/, my models in app/models/posts, etc. I can test the models just fine. The spec for one model looks like...

```
module Posts
  describe Post do
    describe 'Associations' do
      it ...
      end
```

... and everything works fine.

However, the specs for the controllers do not work. The Rails engine is mounted at /posts, yet the controller is Posts::PostController. Thus, the tests look for the controller route to be posts/posts.

```
  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all posts as @posts" do
      Posts::Post.stub(:all) { [mock_post] }
       get :index
       assigns(:posts).should eq([mock_post])
    end
  end
```

which yields...

```
  1) Posts::PostsController GET index assigns all posts as @posts
     Failure/Error: get :index
     ActionController::RoutingError:
     No route matches {:controller=>"posts/posts"}
     # ./spec/controllers/posts/posts_controller_spec.rb:16
```

I've tried all sorts of tricks in the test app's routes file... :namespace, etc, to no avail.

How do I make this work? It seems like it won't, since the engine puts the controller at /posts, yet the namespacing puts the controller at /posts/posts for the purpose of testing.

Answer (score 42):

I'm assuming you're testing your engine with a dummy rails app, like the one that would be generated by [enginex](https://github.com/josevalim/enginex).

Your engine should be mounted in the dummy app:

In `spec/dummy/config/routes.rb`:

```
Dummy::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Posts::Engine => '/posts-prefix'
end
```

My second assumption is that your engine is isolated:

In `lib/posts.rb`:

```
module Posts
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Posts
  end
end
```

I don't know if these two assumptions are really required, but that is how my own engine is structured.

The workaround is quite simple, instead of this

```
get :show, :id => 1
```

use this

```
get :show, {:id => 1, :use_route => :posts}
```

The `:posts` symbol should be the name of your engine and NOT the path where it is mounted.

This works because the get method parameters are passed straight to `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Generator#initialize` (defined [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L366)), which in turn uses `@named_route` to get the correct route from `Rack::Mount::RouteSet#generate` (see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L451) and [here](https://github.com/josh/rack-mount/blob/master/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb#L216)).

Plunging into the rails internals is fun, but quite time consuming, I would not do this every day ;-) .

HTH

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to set this as some sort of global somewhere so it doesn't have to be passed to each of the tests...

Comment: I'd also like to know how you came to know this.

Comment: @RyanBigg The good old failover once my google-fu hits a wall: reading the source and lots of poking around in the rails console. I spent a full hour on this, because it was my first time reading the routing code.

Comment: @RyanBigg you can set it as a before block like this: `before(:each) { @routes = Posts::Engine.routes }`. Found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8140626/299781

Answer (score 22):

I worked around this issue by overriding the `get`, `post`, `put`, and `delete` methods  that are provided, making it so they always pass `use_route` as a parameter.

I used Benoit's answer as a basis for this. Thanks buddy!

```
module ControllerHacks
  def get(action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil)
    process_action(action, parameters, session, flash, "GET")
  end

  # Executes a request simulating POST HTTP method and set/volley the response
  def post(action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil)
    process_action(action, parameters, session, flash, "POST")
  end

  # Executes a request simulating PUT HTTP method and set/volley the response
  def put(action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil)
    process_action(action, parameters, session, flash, "PUT")
  end

  # Executes a request simulating DELETE HTTP method and set/volley the response
  def delete(action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil)
    process_action(action, parameters, session, flash, "DELETE")
  end

  private

  def process_action(action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil, method = "GET")
    parameters ||= {}
    process(action, parameters.merge!(:use_route => :my_engine), session, flash, method)
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include ControllerHacks, :type => :controller
end
```

Comment: Much better than specifying this every time, bookmarked, thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much Ryan for this.  Works like a charm.  Will use this until an even simpler approach comes along.

Answer (score 19):

Use the rspec-rails `routes` directive:

```
describe MyEngine::WidgetsController do
  routes { MyEngine::Engine.routes }

  # Specs can use the engine's routes & named URL helpers
  # without any other special code.
end
```

– [RSpec Rails 2.14 official docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/engine-routes-for-controllers).

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691594/how-to-test-routes-in-a-rails-3-1-mountable-engine/7967503#7967503) answer I chose the following solution:

```
#spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
 # other code
 config.before(:each) { @routes = UserManager::Engine.routes }
end
```

The **additional benefit** is, that you don't need to have the `before(:each)` block in every controller-spec.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. I had the same idea for a solution but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Even if it did work, then you would break all your other tests that are for the rest of your app.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for a problem when you don't have or cannot use `isolate_namespace`:

```
module Posts
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

In controller specs, to fix routes:

```
get :show, {:id => 1, :use_route => :posts_engine}
```

Rails adds _engine to your app routes if you don't use `isolate_namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a gem for my company that provides an API for the applications we're running.  We're using Rails 3.0.9 still, with latest Rspec-Rails (2.10.1). I was having a similar issue where I had defined routes like so in my Rails engine gem.

```
match '/companyname/api_name' => 'CompanyName/ApiName/ControllerName#apimethod'
```

I was getting an error like

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
 No route matches {:controller=>"company_name/api_name/controller_name", :action=>"apimethod"}
```

It turns out I just needed to redefine my route in underscore case so that RSpec could match it.

```
match '/companyname/api_name' => 'company_name/api_name/controller_name#apimethod'
```

I guess Rspec controller tests use a reverse lookup based on underscore case, whereas Rails will setup and interpret the route if you define it in camelcase or underscore case.

Answer (score 0):

It was already mentioned about adding `routes { MyEngine::Engine.routes }`, although it's possible to specify this for all controller tests:

```rb
# spec/support/test_helpers/controller_routes.rb
module TestHelpers
  module ControllerRoutes
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      routes { MyEngine::Engine.routes }
    end

  end
end
```

and use in `rails_helper.rb`:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include TestHelpers::ControllerRoutes, type: :controller
end
```