# Rails engine asset available to app when `path` used, but not if downloaded from rubygems.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

I find this problem a little funky, and need more sets of eyes. I'm making a super simple [gem](https://github.com/ramontayag/backbone_eventbinder_rails) that makes the backbone.eventbinder.js file available to the Rails app that requires this gem.

The problem is that when I add `gem 'backbone_eventbinder_rails', path: '/path/to/repo'` to my app's Gemfile, I can see the file at `http://localhost:3000/assets/backbone.eventbinder.js`. When I use `gem 'backbone_eventbinder_rails', '1.0.2.2'`, I cannot see the asset. I get a `No route matches [GET] "/assets/backbone.eventbinder.js` error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a route? --||-- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Routing#300--use-route-to-force-named-routes-in-url-for --||-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200654/how-do-i-write-a-rails-3-1-engine-controller-test-in-rspec

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the gem isn't picking up the vendor files.

I would change:

```
s.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib}/**/*"] + ["MIT-LICENSE", "Rakefile", "README.md"]
s.test_files = Dir["test/**/*"]
```

To:

```
s.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
s.executables   = s.files.grep(%r{^bin/}).map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
s.test_files    = s.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
s.require_paths = ["lib"]
```

Otherwise I thinks it's got somehting to do with:

```
module BackboneEventbinderRails
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

being changed to:

```
class BackboneEventbinderRails::Engine < ::Rails::Engine
end
```

in version 1.0.2.2

And why move Engine to a seperate file? Since the gem only makes javascript available i wouldn't bother about lib.