# Multiple Rails engine rspec controller test not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, rails-engines

I have multiple Rails engines in my Rails 4 beta1 application. I'm installed `rspec-rails` gem to every engines. And I created my engine following command:

```
rails plugin new store_frontend --dummy-path=spec/dummy -d postgresql --skip-test-unit --mountable
```

In my engine's dummy application I configured database and routes. Here is example routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount StoreFrontend::Engine => "/store"
end
```

When I run rspec inside first engine I get following errors:

```
  1) StoreAdmin::DashboardController GET 'index' returns http success
     Failure/Error: get 'index'
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"store_admin/dashboard"}
     # ./spec/controllers/store_admin/dashboard_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <module:StoreAdmin>'
```

And here is my controller test /It's generated from Rails/:

```
require 'spec_helper'

module StoreFrontend
  describe HomeController do

    describe "GET 'index'" do
      it "returns http success" do
        get 'index'
        response.should be_success
      end
    end

  end
end
```

It seems like controller test is not working. I have model tests and it's working fine. Any idea?

**UPDATE 1:**
My application structure:

```
bin/
config/
db/
lib/
log/
public/
tmp/
engine1/
engine2/
engine3/
```

Comment: spec shown and spec result do not relate to the same code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is very simple. Add `use_route` to your controller test. Here is the example.

```
module StoreFrontend
  describe HomeController do

    describe "GET 'index'" do
      it "returns http success" do
        get 'index', use_route: 'store_frontend' # in my case
        response.should be_success
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: How does changing `StoreFronted` fix `StoreAdmin::DashboardController` ? How does this fix `No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"store_admin/dashboard"}`?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200654/how-do-i-write-a-rails-3-1-engine-controller-test-in-rspec

Comment: Thanks, 'use_route' resolved the UrlGenerationError issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I didn't have exactly the same problem described in the original question, but your answer applies. I have a series of 'Lookup' models derived from a base model using STI (Single Table Inheritance) and a single controller for all Lookup derived types. RSpec was spitting out the same UrlGenerationError.  

We ran into a similar

Answer (score 3):

The configuration and spec you show are for `StoreFrontend` but the error is for `StoreAdmin::DashboardController`.  So it seems like you are just confused about which engine you are testing and/or which engine is failing.

Of course the simple solution is to create the missing route `{:action=>"index", :controller=>"store_admin/dashboard"}`

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the routing correct when testing Rails engine controllers with Rspec, I typically add the following code to my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, :type => :controller) { @routes = YourEngineName::Engine.routes }
  config.before(:each, :type => :routing)    { @routes = YourEngineName::Engine.routes }
end
```