# Can't test engine routes under Rails 3.2 + Rspec 2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, routes, rspec-rails, rule-engine

In my engine 'Utilizer', I'm trying to test routes with Rspec 3.2.
Namespace are isolated

```
# lib/utilizer/engine.rb
module Utilizer
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
        isolate_namespace Utilizer
        ...
    end
end
```

The engine is mounted to the dummy app:

```
    # spec/dummy/config/routes.rb
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      mount Utilizer::Engine => "/utilizer", as: 'utilizer'
    end
```

To the spec_helper.rb I've added a couple of configures as below (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15394885)):

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.before(:each, type: :routing)    { @routes = Utilizer::Engine.routes }
  ...
end
```

When I defined a route:

```
# config/routes.rb
Utilizer::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :auths, id: /\d+/, only: [:destroy]
end
```

Rake shows it properly for the dummy app:

```
$ spec/dummy > bundle exec rake routes

$ utilizer /utilizer Utilizer::Engine
$ Routes for Utilizer::Engine:
$ auth DELETE /auths/:id(.:format) utilizer/auths#destroy {:id=>/\d+/}
```

BUT both Rspec tests

```
# spec/routing/auths_routing_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Auths page routing" do

  let!(:auth) { create(:utilizer_auth) } # factory is working properly by itself

  describe "#destroy" do
    let!(:action) { { controller: "utilizer/auths", action: "destroy", id: auth.id } }
    specify { { delete: "/auths/#{ auth.id }" }.should route_to(action) }
    specify { { delete: auth_path(auth) }.should route_to(action) }
  end
end
```

fail with errors (for the first and second tests correspondingly):

```
No route matches "/auths/1"
No route matches "/utilizer/auths/1"
```

But, Holmes, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since RSpec 2.14 you can use the following:

```
describe "Auths page routing" do
  routes { Utilizer::Engine.routes }
  # ...
end
```

Source: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/668

Comment: Worked for me. The config.before did not work under rails 4.0.2. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've fount a solution in Exoth's comment at the end of [this discussion on Github](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/539) (thanks to [Brandan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133199/brandan)).

In my spec_helper instead of

```
config.before(:each, type: :routing) { @routes = Utilizer::Engine.routes }
```

I use

```
config.before(:each, type: :routing) do
  @routes = Utilizer::Engine.routes
  assertion_instance.instance_variable_set(:@routes, Utilizer::Engine.routes)
end
```

and it works.