# Rspec not logging me in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, bdd, factory-bot

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13369734/2680520) to see how to test a session controller and wrote something like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsController do
  context "We should login to the system and create a session" do
    let :credentials do
      {:user_name => "MyString", :password => "someSimpleP{ass}"}
    end

    let :user do
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, credentials)
    end

    before :each do
      post :create , credentials
    end

    it "should create a session" do
      puts user.inspect
      puts session[:user_id]
      #session[:user_id].should == user.id
    end
  end
end
```

Based on that I created a factory girl user:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, :class => 'User' do
    name "sample_user"
    email "MyString@gmail.com"
    user_name "MyString"
    password "someSimpleP{ass}"
  end
end
```

Now it all works - exceot for the `before :each do` statement - it never "logs" the "user" in - thus I cannot test the controllers functionality of, is a session properly created?

Now most would say, use capybara and test it through that way - but that's wrong, IMO - sure if I'm doing front end testing that would work, but I'm testing controller based logic. Can some one tell me why this isn't working? routing works fine.

My `puts session[:user_id]` is coming up nil, when it shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood SessionsController and RegistrationsController.

A Session is for an user who has already registered, not for creating an user. #create in SessionController means to create a session, not an user.

RegistrationController is for creating user with full details including password_confirmation.

To test SessionsController, you need to create a valid user in FactoryGirl at first, then use his credentials say email and password to sign in.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the code - or maybe there is a mis understanding here - but FactoryGirl.create creates a new user object in the database ....

Comment: @Adam, yes you are right, it's my misunderstanding, your process is correct. How do you create the session in controller? Custom code? If you are using Devise, the session hash is different from that.

Comment: Hi, Billy. It took me way too long (and some testing on my machine) to figure out what was going on, but check out my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`let` is lazily evaluated, even for the `before` clause, so the user has not been created as of the time you do the `post` to login. If you change to using `let!`, you'll avoid this problem.

Comment: Peter, as per your research, I think the problem can be fixed by replace second `let` to `let!`, to read as `let! :user do...`. Any thoughts?

Comment: That's what I intended my answer to say. :-)  Did you think I was referring to the first `let` or even both `let`s? I guess I should update my answer to be more explicit.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I only read the first sentence which is the most important, and neglected the rest completely:) Forget that comment. Thank you, Peter. I just met similar situation so I referred here.